# PopupControlExtender

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, toolkitscriptmanager

I am trying to add new asp.net page to already existing asp.net website which contain scriptmanager. On this asp.net page I am using "PopupControlExtender". So when I try to run website then it shows me error that "Use toolkitscriptmanager instead of scriptmanager".

Is their any way to use scriptmanager only instead of toolkitmanager or is thier any effect on all ready existing pages after using toolkitscriptmanager instead of scriptmanager?

Answer (score 0):

the toolkitmanager inherits from scriptmanager. so anything your using scriptmanager will work with the toolkitmanager.
you can read more about it here:
http://blog.turlov.com/2008/05/scriptmanager-vs-toolkitscriptmanager.html